# Sencha Touch 2: dataview not visible in android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, sencha-touch-2, dataview, invisible

I have been developing an android application by sencha touch 2. Current weather and daily forecast were built in html type. I want hourly forecast will be shown in a horizontal scrollable panel, so I had to used DataView type (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView)

Unfortunately, I can't make it work in Android emulator. Please take a look at the screenshot below, to see the difference between emulator and chrome. I also didn't see any error in ADT and chrome console log.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxzrt.png

Here is my sourcecode, these items are inside a card of a carousel. Thank you for your time to read my problem.

```
items: [{
            height: '50%',
            html: tplCurr.apply(obj)
        }, {
            height: '10%',
            xtype: 'dataview',  
            cls: 'hourly-container',
            scrollable: {
                direction: 'horizontal',
                directionLock : true
            },
            inline: { wrap: false },
            data: obj.hourly,
            itemTpl: tplHourly
        }, {
            height: '40%',
            xtype: 'panel',  
            cls:  'daily-container',
            fullscreen: true,
            scrollable: {
                direction: 'vertical',
                directionLock : true
            },
            items: dayItems 
        }]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the parent container's code or at least the layout property. Are you using 'vbox' for the layout? Try using the flex property on each container instead of height (e.g. flex:5, flex:1, flex:4)

Answer (score 0):

Try this please,

```
layout:{
   type:'vertical'   
},
items: [{
            flex:4,
            html: tplCurr.apply(obj)
        }, {
            flex:1,
            xtype: 'dataview',  
            cls: 'hourly-container',

            scrollable: {
                direction: 'horizontal',
                directionLock : true
            },
            inline: { wrap: false },
            data: obj.hourly,
            itemTpl: tplHourly
        }, {
            flex:2,
            xtype: 'panel',  
            cls:  'daily-container',
            fullscreen: true,
            scrollable: {
                direction: 'vertical',
                directionLock : true
            },
            items: dayItems 
        }]
```

Comment: you might explain briefly what's the issue with what she/he's doing and what you did to correct